# Sql query: Link data to all days between two given dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with that looks like

```
    Date    |  BookID   |  Rating  |  Review
2012-10-12  |    2      |    3     |    3
2012-10-13  |    2      |    7     |    9
2012-10-16  |    3      |    4     |    2
```

Each day, a book can receive a number of rating and review
I am trying to write a query that given two dates, it displays the rating and review for each book, for EACH day in between the two given dates. Even when that day has no rating or no review I still want to display the date and the BookID
For example, in the table above, I want the query to return something like

```
 Date       |  BookID   |  Rating  |  Review
2012-10-12  |    2      |    3     |    3
2012-10-13  |    2      |    7     |    9
2012-10-14  |    2      |   null   |   null
2012-10-15  |    2      |   null   |   null
2012-10-16  |    3      |    4     |    2
```

How can I do this please?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: SQL is *Structured Query Language* not a database. What RDBMS? sql server, mysql, oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--set up test data

DECLARE @Reviews TABLE([Date] date, BookId int, Rating int, Review int)

INSERT INTO @Reviews VALUES
('2012-10-12', 2, 3, 3),
('2012-10-13', 2, 7, 9),
('2012-10-16', 3, 4, 2)

--setup query parameters
DECLARE @StartDate date, 
        @EndDate date
SELECT  @StartDate = '2012-10-12', 
        @EndDate = '2012-10-16'

--run query

;WITH IntervalSet AS
(
    SELECT @StartDate AS [Date]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date]) AS [Date]
    FROM   IntervalSet 
    WHERE  DATEADD(DAY,1,[Date])<=@EndDate
) 
SELECT  I.[Date], B.BookId, R.Rating, R.Review 
FROM    
(
        SELECT  BookId, Min([Date]) as EarliestDate
        FROM    @Reviews
        GROUP BY BookId
) B
JOIN    IntervalSet I
        ON  I.[Date] >= b.EarliestDate
LEFT
JOIN    @Reviews R
        ON  R.[Date] = I.[Date]
        AND R.BookId = B.BookId
ORDER BY I.[Date], B.BookId
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

This gives the results:

```
Date       BookId      Rating      Review
---------- ----------- ----------- -----------
2012-10-12 2           3           3
2012-10-13 2           7           9
2012-10-14 2           NULL        NULL
2012-10-15 2           NULL        NULL
2012-10-16 2           NULL        NULL
2012-10-16 3           4           2
```

That's one extra row than the results you posted, but I believe is correct - it doesn't return any rows for a bookid before the first review which looks like what you were after

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

**[SQLFIDDLEEXAMPLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cca52/29)**

```
WITH mycte AS
     (
         SELECT cast('2012-01-01' AS datetime) DateValue
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DateValue + 1
         FROM    mycte
         WHERE   DateValue + 1 < '2014-12-31'
     )


SELECT
CONVERT(char(10), mycte.DateValue,126) as Date,
b.BookID,
(SELECT Rating FROM tbl WHERE BookID = b.BookID
                        AND Date = mycte.DateValue) as Rating,
(SELECT Review FROM tbl WHERE BookID = b.BookID
                        AND Date = mycte.DateValue) as Review
FROM    mycte, (SELECT distinct BookID
               FROM tbl) b
WHERE mycte.DateValue >= '2012-10-12'
AND mycte.DateValue <= '2012-10-15'
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Result:

```
|       DATE | BOOKID | RATING | REVIEW |
-----------------------------------------
| 2012-10-12 |      2 |      3 |      3 |
| 2012-10-12 |      3 | (null) | (null) |
| 2012-10-13 |      2 |      7 |      9 |
| 2012-10-13 |      3 | (null) | (null) |
| 2012-10-14 |      2 | (null) | (null) |
| 2012-10-14 |      3 | (null) | (null) |
| 2012-10-15 |      2 | (null) | (null) |
| 2012-10-15 |      3 | (null) | (null) |
```